# Are there programmable automount/autofs hooks in linux/systemd?

Tags: linux, mount, systemd, automount

I'd like to have a program executed before a mount attempt is made for a particular device/share/mount.
For example, I'd like for autofs/amd to control /data/{1..10}, and when a process opens /data/4 (and /data/4 is not currently mounted), a script is invoked, such as '/usr/local/bin/preparedata 4' (4 being the mount point name within the autofs controlled directory), prior to the attempt to mount.
For example, I could dynamically attach an iSCSI LUN (which would be referenced in the autofs map), or startup a remote system/VM which has an NFS export  (which is specified in the map).

I'd be glad to add details if missing.

Update: I've noticed that systemd appears to be intercepting open() calls, is there some way to do this particularly in systemd?

Comment: Any luck with this?  I have a similar need.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189404/how-to-keep-a-redundant-home-directory-for-offline-use

Comment: nope.. only thing I can imagine is modifying some underlying code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autofs itself can run a custom script or program to dynamically provide "the map", i.e. the mount options and arguments autofs uses for mounting.

As an example, to automount home directories from an NFS-server one may prefer to use a pattern like "/home/user12/user123456" for the homedir paths to limit the number of sub-directories on a server when there are many users.

To dynamically mount such home directories, you could put this in your /etc/auto.master:

```
/home    program:/usr/local/sbin/autofs-home-mapper.sh
```

The script /usr/local/sbin/autofs-home-mapper.sh could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-fstype=nfs4,relatime nfs.example.com:/exported/${1%????}/${1}"
```

When the local directory /home/johndoe is accessed, autofs will run the script
with one argument:  `johndoe`

Output of this script will then be:

```
-fstype=nfs4,relatime nfs.example.com:/exported/joh/johndoe
```

...which is then used by autofs to mount /home/johndoe

Don't forget to set eXecute permission on the script, as it can be difficult to track down a bug like that.

More information in `man 5 auto.master` (look under "map-type") and `man 5 autofs`.

Comment: ahh, I saw that when originally researching, but thought it was run once to generate the map, not run each time a keyword is looked up in the map.  If the latter is the case, then this solves the problem quite nicely!

Comment: It'll be run every time it needs to get mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`x-systemd.requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.requires=), and [`x-systemd.after=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.before=) for hooks executed before mounting.

These options can be specified inside `/etc/fstab`.

---

Related question: [Hook before an `.automount` unmounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406934/143394).